# How to install WINE on linux mint 19.3?

Tags: linux-mint, software-installation, wine

I followed all the instructions, and I got this error:

```
$ sudo apt install wine-stable

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine-stable : Depends: wine-stable-i386 (= 5.0.2~bionic)
               Depends: wine-stable-amd64 (= 5.0.2~bionic) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

how can I fix this?

Comment: `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just wine and not stable version?

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```